# «Прошли сто лет» или «Прошло сто лет»?

Tags: единственное-множественное-число, количественно-именное-сочетание

Делая курсовую работу, я столкнулся с фразой **«Прошл... сто лет»**. Как будет правильнее: **«Прошли сто лет»**, или же все-таки **«Прошло сто лет»**, и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошл**о** сто лет (нейтральное выражение длительности временного промежутка).
Если нужна ссылка на ранее упомянутый промежуток времени:

> Гонконг был отдан в аренду Великобритании на сто лет (реально на 99).
>   *Эти сто лет прошл**и***,  и в 1997 году он стал китайской провинцией
>   Сянган.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение :)